# Webapi async upload, buffer and memory usage

Tags: file-upload, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, buffer

I'm trying out the code in this article [Part 2: File Upload and Multipart MIME](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

It's basically a form post to webapi task that does async read

```
 await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

To avoid full upload buffering and excessive memory usage, I also put in the suggestion from this article [Dealing with large files in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)

It suggests creating

```
   public class NoBufferPolicySelector : WebHostBufferPolicySelector
```

and config

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace
  (typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new NoBufferPolicySelector());
```

However, when I test uploading two 1G file using IE and Firefox from another machine, without the NoBufferPolicySelector, they use about 90M of memory.  With, about 180M.

Is that all?  Does this mean WebApi2 already have built-in memory buffer control?  Does the extra policy selector code necessary?  Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

StreamContent not buffered according to ["the guy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171977/2056402)

```
public class WebHostBufferPolicySelector 
  : IHostBufferPolicySelector
{
   ......

 public virtual bool UseBufferedOutputStream
      (HttpResponseMessage response)
 {
      return !(content is StreamContent 
            || content is PushStreamContent);
```

Comment: If you look carefully at the answer you mentioned, this is for the output, so a response of a request. Here the OP is asking for the upload, so for the buffering of a request, driven by `UseBufferedInputStream` (which seems to return always `true`) and not `UseBufferedOutputStream` as you mentioned.