# I want to unzip a binary data of zip file in javascripte (Decompressing)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var url = "http://localhost:9996/api/GetZipFile?id=1-1" ;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            // reslut is binary data of zip file 
            // how can read(Decompressing) file and get files from this file
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Falid2");
    }
});
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JS ZIP library here are some

- [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)
- [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)

Comment: Also beware of `$.ajax` and binary content, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197919/1992669) for example.