# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) Error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, zip

On my MVC project, I have a POST request to a Web API using `XmlHttpRequest`.

I send an array of documents' routes in a JSON format and expecting to get from the server a Zip file (ArrayBuffer).

```
self.zipDocs = function (docs, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseBody);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", '../API/documents/zip', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    console.log(docs);
    xhr.send(docs);

    var arraybuffer = xhr.response;
    var blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], { type: "application/zip" });
    saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
}
```

And my ZipDocs function on the WebAPI (using the DotNetZip library):

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("documents/zip")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ZipDocs([FromBody] string[] docs)
    {

    using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
    {
        zipFile.AddFiles(docs, false, "");
        return ZipContentResult(zipFile);
    }
}

protected HttpResponseMessage ZipContentResult(ZipFile zipFile)
{
    // inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171977/92756
    var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
    {
       zipFile.Save(stream);
        stream.Close(); // After save we close the stream to signal that we are done writing.
    }, "application/zip");

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = pushStreamContent };
}
```

But the response I'm getting from the server is:

> ```
> POST http://localhost:1234/MyProject/API/documents/zip 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
> ```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@David Duponchel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1992669/david-duponchel) I used the [jquery.binarytransport.js](http://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport) library, I sent the data to the API as JSON and got back the Zip File as Binary.

This is my JavaScript ZipDocs function:

```
self.zipDocs = function (docs, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../API/documents/zip",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "binary",
        data: docs,
        processData: false,
        success: function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "ZippedDocuments.zip");
            callback("Success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            callback("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

The API's code remains the same.

That works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Based on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)

You might want to try

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

And your code is missing a semicolon on

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
```

Comment: Are those mime types allowed on server side ?

Comment: have you try utf-8 ? xhr.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8")