# Is it safe to return a Stream in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

My WebAPI needs to return a Stream.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Fill the Stream
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new OkObjectResult(stream);
}
```

The above would not work as `stream` is disposed before the Client can get it. So I simply changed it to:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
//Fill the Stream
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return new OkObjectResult(stream);
```

I wonder if it is safe to return a stream from a WebAPI. My doubt is that the garbage collector could dispose `stream` before the client has finished to get/download the content.

Comment: You can convert to `byte[]` and then return

Comment: @Pietro Have you considered `StreamContent`? Please check the following [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168683/webapi-streamcontent-vs-pushstreamcontent)